# Change Return type error in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, return-type

I keep getting the following error in Eclipse:

```
"The method printf(String, Object[]) in the type PrintStream is not applicable for the arguments (String, String)"
```

Here is the code:

```
public class names {

private String nameOne;
  public void setName(String name){
     nameOne=name;
  }
  public String getName(){
     return nameOne;
  }
  public void saying(){
     System.out.printf("Your name is %s", getName());
  }
}
```

Please help explain what I should do. I tried to remove "String", but that was silly. I'm somewhat new so a detailed explaination would not be overkill (though the short, simple, correct responses are always the best).

Comment: This code compiles fine for me.

Comment: What version of Java are you using? Maybe `printf` was changed recently to accept `Object...` instead of `Object[]`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis java -version
java version "1.8.0"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0-b132)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.0-b70, mixed mode)

Comment: @user3473227: Your question says you're using Eclipse, but your comment states your Java version by running `java`. You realize that Eclipse doesn't use the `java` command to detect compile errors?

Comment: @ruakh Version: Kepler Service Release 2
Build id: 20140224-0627

Comment: You should really check the compiler compliance level for Eclipse. You could probably fix it by passing `new Object[] {getName()};` as an argument instead of `getName()`.

Comment: @user3473227 check my answer now, will fix your issue

Comment: Solitirios deserves  the credit for the answer for pointing out the  actual issue and guiding Dileep to the root cause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **The issue was due to the wrong  Compiler compliance level**

To solve it you must change your Compiler compliance level in eclipse by doing this

1) Right-click on your project

2) Click Properties

3) Click the "Java Compiler" option on the left menu

4) Under JDK compliance section on the right, change it to "1.5" or above

> **Java Compiler compliance level**
>
> The Compiler compliance level indicates that which JDK level of source
>   must be used for compilation.

**For eg :**

> If you are using some
>   components which is defined in earlier versions of Java JDK and was
>   removed from the later versions. Then you must use the older version
>   of JDK to compile your code. For this the eclipse provide the use of
>   multiple compliance level, ie; even if you are using the latest version
>   of JDK. You can tell the compiler to compile with an older version.

The JDK 1.5 implemented the printf() method in the java.io.PrintStream class that offers the same formatting capabilities as the printf function in stdio library in C. 
Look on [Other Developer-Friendly Enhancements](http://conferences.embarcadero.com/article/32241#_Toc81577822) for details.

Comment: Why will this solve the issue? `getName()` already returns a `String`.

Comment: Yes i don't know why i am searching for that, but it works for me.

Comment: Are you saying this works for you, but OP's code doesn't? Can you explain why?

Comment: `Your name is ` this is the output i get when i use `String.valueOf`. And `Your name is null` is the value without using that. And i know the reason for that. but don't know what cause that exception.

Comment: So you are _not_ seeing the same problem as OP? And therefore your answer is dealing with something entirely different.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis check my guess would that be the issue ??

Comment: Their version of `printf` accepts a `String` and an `Object[]`, but OP is providing a `String` and a `String`. That's what their error says. `nameOne` is a field in their class.

Comment: You can always edit or delete your question. (Reply if you have, I'll change my vote if I think your answer is correct.)

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I Solved and it works like charm. I regenerated the error by using 1.4 compliance level and changed that to 1.7 and it solved the issue. B)

Comment: I removed my down vote. If you also explain what this change does and why it would be needed, I will upvite.

Comment: The difference I wanted you to look for is the difference in `PrintStream` between 1.4 and current versions.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis That i don't know, haven't found any relevant information. Try it yourself and update me if anything is found.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis You are a champ. This is why stack exchange is awesome!